# error while installing jupyter notebook with pip

Tags: python, installation, pip, jupyter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xO8do.png)

this is the error I am getting while installing jupyter with pip
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [6 lines of output]

```
  Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.
  This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through
  the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/

  Checking for Rust toolchain....
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> pywinpty

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

how can I resolve this??

Comment: try to update Pip by running the command `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`.

Comment: Looks like a package called Cargo is missing.
If what @ShivamPandey said doesn't help, try installing Cargo manually `curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you fixed on using a 32 bit version of python?

Comment: Where the error message says `This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/`, exactly what part of that was not clear?

Answer (score 1):

Your error screenshot shows that the issue is not with Jupyter but with dependency: [pywinpty](https://pypi.org/project/pywinpty/)

From pywinpty [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pywinpty/):

> To compile pywinpty sources, you must have Rust installed. Optionally, you can also have Winpty's C header and library files available on your include path.

Rust is a dependency for pywinpty and pywinpty is dependency for the version of the Jupyter youre trying to install.

Either install Rust or install a version Jupyter that does not depend on pywinpty. Not much to add without knowing what version/distribution of Jupyter you are trying to install and how.